# Extract columns from table using loop

Tags: awk, sed, variable

I have this matrix.

```
#chr    st  start   PM1_r1   PM2_r1   PM3_r1   PM1_r2  PM2_r2 PM3_r2
chr1    -   10625   0   0   0   0   0   0
chr1    +   16616   0.10217712  0   0   1   0   0
chr1    -   120482  0   0   0.50105411  0   0   1
chr1    -   247355  0   0   0.50105411  0   0   1
chr1    +   535689  0.10217712  0   0   1   0   0
```

#Extra column to be inserted

```
file4=formatedFile1
file5=formatedFile2
file6=formatedFile3
```

Desired output is achieved by this command,

```
   awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,"'$file4'" }' file

chr1    -   10625   0   0   formatedFile1
chr1    +   16616   0.10217712  1   formatedFile1
chr1    -   120482  0   0   formatedFile1
chr1    -   247355  0   0   formatedFile1
chr1    +   535689  0.10217712  1   formatedFile1

awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,"'$file5'" }' filename 

chr1    -   10625   0   0   formatedFile2
chr1    +   16616   0   0   formatedFile2
chr1    -   120482  0   0   formatedFile2
chr1    -   247355  0   0   formatedFile2
chr1    +   535689  0   0   formatedFile2



awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { print $1,$2,$3,$6,$9,"'$file6'" }' file

chr1    -   10625   0   0   formatedFile3
chr1    +   16616   0   0   formatedFile3
chr1    -   120482  0.50105411  1   formatedFile3
chr1    -   247355  0.50105411  1   formatedFile3
chr1    +   535689  0   0   formatedFile3
```

The values start from column4 and goes to column6. Round2 value starts from column7 to column9.
The file is long, and want to do it with loop

```
    file4=formatedFile1
    file5=formatedFile2
    file6=formatedFile3
    
    recurrenceCol=3
    for col in 4 5 6
    do
        col1=$col
        col2=$((col+recurrenceCol))

        echo $col1
        echo $col2
        id="file"$col
        out=out"$ID" 

awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { print $1,$2,$3,$'$col1', $'$col2', "'$ID'" }' file 
   


    done
```

The script does not give desired output as it is not printing the filename in column6. The column6 value file4 should have been formatedFile1

Output from script.

```
chr1    -   10625   0   0   file4
chr1    +   16616   0.10217712  1   file4
chr1    -   120482  0   0   file4
chr1    -   247355  0   0   file4
chr1    +   535689  0.10217712  1   file4


chr1    -   10625   0   0   file5
chr1    +   16616   0   0   file5
chr1    -   120482  0   0   file5
chr1    -   247355  0   0   file5
chr1    +   535689  0   0   file5
```

and so on .

Comment: 1. You're doing command-substition (`$(...)`) here rather than arithmetic. Try `col2=$((col+recurrenceCol))`. 2. Why you are you catting a file into awk? If you give awk a filename argument, then you can just use the `FILENAME` variable. 3. And why the same file multiple times? Is there only one input file? Or several?  4. Whatever it is that you're trying to do (I have no idea, and I've spent 5 minutes trying to understand what you're saying), this should probably be done entirely within awk and not as a shell for loop around awk.

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer. I reworked on the command, it print column4 and column5 properly, but not printing column6 correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whey you want to call awk multiple times in a shell loop rather than just do it all in 1 call to awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, the thing you missed was the use of the bash's `indirection operator ${!varname}` which will ouput the value of the variable held in varname.

Also, the canonical | right way, to use shell variables in awk code is via the `-v awkvar=shell_data` , rather than plugging them directly in an awk statement.

```
    file4=formatedFile1
    file5=formatedFile2
    file6=formatedFile3
    
    recurrenceCol=3
    for col in 4 5 6
    do
        col1=$col
        col2=$((col+recurrenceCol))

        echo $col1
        echo $col2
        id="file"$col
        out=out"$ID"
        f=${!id}

   awk -v col1="$col1" \
       -v col2="$col2" \
       -v id="$f" '
BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
{
 print $1,$2,$3,$(col1),$(col2),id
}
    ' file
 # echo --- -- --- --- --- ---
    done
```